# how do I update IRB on my mac (OS 10.9.4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb

I am not sure how I can update my irb. You can see the version that I have below

```
  irb 0.9.6(09/06/30)
```

I have also updated my ruby using rvm. You can see that I am on version 2.1.2

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

Trying to figure out how to update irb

Answer (score 1):

`irb` comes as part of `ruby`. You don't update it separately.

Answer (score 1):

As infused said, irb comes with your using ruby, and in irb, with 'RUBY_VERSION', you can check the using ruby version

When I'm using 2.0

```
#rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p576
Using /home/yi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576
#irb
2.0.0-p576 :001 > RUBY_VERSION
 => "2.0.0" 
2.0.0-p576 :002 >
```

when switch to 1.9.3

```
#rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p448
Using /home/yi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448
#irb
1.9.3-p448 :001 > RUBY_VERSION
 => "1.9.3" 
1.9.3-p448 :002 >
```